# PHP OOP Static Property Syntax Error

Tags: php, static-members

Why doesn't

```
public static $CURRENT_TIME = time() + 7200;
```

work (Error):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('

but

```
class Database {
  public static $database_connection;

  private static $host = "xxx";
  private static $user = "xxx";
  private static $pass = "xxx";
  private static $db = "xxx";

  public static function DatabaseConnect(){
    self::$database_connection = new mysqli(self::$host,self::$user,self::$pass,self::$db);
    self::$database_connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    return self::$database_connection;
  }
}
```

does work.

I'm new to OOP, I'm so confused.

Comment: Define "errors out", say, by providing the error. It might be worth a look at [How to ask great technical questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: No doubt a parse error along the lines of `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('`.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot initialize any member variable (property) with a non-constant expression. In other words, no calling functions right there where you declare it.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

The best answer I can give as to *why*? Because the static field initializers aren't really run with any sort of context. When a static method is called, you are in the context of that function call. When a non-static property is set, you are in the context of the constructor. What context are you in when you set a static field?

Comment: +1 Has nothing to do with it being static and good "straight from the horse's mouth" quote via the manual.

Comment: what i was trying to get from this was why does setting a property inside a static method work, but not for a static property outside of a method.

Comment: @ShaneLarson see my edit for an answer as to "why"

Answer (score 3):

Class members can only contain constants and literals, not the result of function calls, as it is not a constant value.

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

Comment: No class members can contain the result of function calls, static or not.

Comment: Receive an `E_STRICT`? No, you will receive a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

They have explain why it doesn't work. This would be the work around.

```
class SomeClass {
   public static $currentTime = null;

   __construct() {
      if (self::$currentTime === null) self::$currentTime = time() + 7200;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained why you can't. But maybe you're looking for a work-around ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BuZGqV)):

```
My_Class::$currentTime = time() + 7200;

class My_Class
{
    public static $currentTime;
    ...
}
```

You're *not* looking for a constructor, you're looking for static initialization.